# RTD compiles all my docs including foreign docs from git submodules

Tags: python-sphinx, git-submodules, read-the-docs

I'm experimenting with [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/) and [ReadTheDocs](http://readthedocs.org/) (RTD) to compile my documentation on every GitHub push. Unfortunately, RTD found multiple `doc`/`docs` folders containing a `conf.py` file.

My [repository](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) uses git sub-modules to embed third party libraries. Some of them are also documented using Sphinx. I assume the biggest (long lasting documentation build) wins and overwrites all static HTML pages in the final RTD view.

How can I exclude or tell RTD to ignore the folders of these sub-modules:

```
lib/cocotb
lib/osvvm
lib/vunit
docs/source/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme
```

My documentation is located here:

```
docs/source/conf.py
docs/source/index.rst
```

As far as I have found, RTD does support `*.yml` files, but there is no entry to define the documentation root folder.

Any ideas to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main documentation folder and its `conf.py` can be configured in the *Advanced Settings* tab in the per project settings.

Example value: `documentation/conf.py`

Answer (score 0):

Inside `conf.py`, there is a list that looks like this

```
 # List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
 # directories to ignore when looking for source files.
 exclude_patterns = []
```

You can put the files you want to ignore inside it like

```
exclude_patterns = ["lib/cocotb", "lib/osvvm", "lib/vunit", "docs/_themes/sphinx_rtd_theme"]
```

Please note that here the pattern is relative to the source directory, you can put `/` at the beginning of each file pattern above to make this more clear.

Comment: When I compile my docs locally, these folders are not included. Excluding `*.rst`or other source files from search, does not prevent RTD from finding multiple `conf.py` files all over the repository. The `conf.py` file is located in `docs/source`. So these lib directories are out of scope.

Comment: You can try to specify all the relative path of `conf.py` in `exclude_patterns` to see if those files are still be included when you build